# Помогите составить функцию поиска

Tags: c#, winforms

Надо в Richtextbox найти строку содержащую слово введенное в textbox2 и выделить ее красным

```
 if (textBox2.TextLength == 0) MessageBox.Show("Поисковый запрос пуст");
        else
        {
            textBox1.SelectAll();
            int k = textBox1.Lines.Count();
            string str = textBox2.Text;
            int start = 0, start1 = 0;
            for (int j=0; j<k; j++)
            {
                string s = textBox1.Lines[j];
                if (s.LastIndexOf(str) >= 0)
                {
                    start1 = textBox2.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
                    start += start1;
                    textBox1.Select(start, str.Length);
                    textBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение

---

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            var selectedText = textBox1.SelectedText;

            int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(selectedText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(index, selectedText.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Selected text not found");
                return;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(@"Поисковый запрос пуст");

    }
```